# KCFinder standalone

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, web-applications, kcfinder

I have been trying and searching here on how to do exactly this:

http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/demos/standalone

I cannot find a single post, documentation or answer about this. I have tried to search on documentation about this, samples, demos, I even inspected it with Firefox. The funny thing is that when I inspect it with Firefox I can see that they use a "standalone.js" which doesn't exist anywhere when you download KCFinder nor online (I also googled it!)...

I tried to make an iframe pointing at the browse.php?images but it didn't work neither (the window was opening but KCFinder wasn't loading any content from the folder)...

I wonder if I am missing something really basic or even if I am the only person in the world who has this problem. Am I making it too complicated?